# How do I add a group reviewer in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I periodically need to add more than 10 people to MR and I do it manually. I add only one person at a time, through the search. Can I somehow add the whole team to the reviewers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does not seem to be supported, and could be added as a feature request, to be referenced in [Epic: Merge request reviewers](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/1823).

The alternative is to use [quick actions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html#issues-merge-requests-and-epics), with GitLab 13.7+ ([issue 241244](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/241244))

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/uploads/ffe12dc8a9f89212e6e2b1a0ba8ebdd3/image.png]

But that presupposes you know the users' names beforehand.